# Percentage Text Box component in Angular 10

Tags: angular10

How to restrict textbox to take/type input 0~100 percentage only in angular 10? it should not take input greater than 100

Comment: Depending on the context (which is not a text box), you could use `<input type="number" min="0" max="100">`, ie: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: Thank you @caramiriel

Comment: Dear Caramiriel after setting max and min value it should not let me type greater than max value